# Failed to find provider in android TV Preferences fragment

Tags: android, android-tv, preferencescreen

Getting Failed to find provider com.google.android.katniss.search.searchapi.VoiceInteractionProvider for user 0; expected to find a valid ContentProvider for this authority for tv Preference Fragment

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.omniwyse.tvprefdemo, PID: 2025
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.omniwyse.tvprefdemo/com.omniwyse.tvprefdemo.SettingActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class <unknown>
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2913)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3048)
        at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:78)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:108)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:68)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1808)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6669)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:858)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class <unknown>
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class <unknown>
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:492)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
        at android.support.v17.preference.BaseLeanbackPreferenceFragment.onCreateRecyclerView(BaseLeanbackPreferenceFragment.java:42)
        at android.support.v14.preference.PreferenceFragment.onCreateView(PreferenceFragment.java:270)
        at android.support.v17.preference.LeanbackPreferenceFragment.onCreateView(LeanbackPreferenceFragment.java:54)
        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2522)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1298)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2426)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2205)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2161)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2062)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchMoveToState(FragmentManager.java:3051)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2998)
        at android.app.Fragment.performActivityCreated(Fragment.java:2537)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1318)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2426)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2205)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2161)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2062)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchMoveToState(FragmentManager.java:3051)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2998)
        at android.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:182)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7143)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7127)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1271)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2893)
```

```
public class SettingsFragment extends LeanbackSettingsFragment {
    @Override
    public void onPreferenceStartInitialScreen() {

        startPreferenceFragment(new PrefsFragment());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceStartFragment(PreferenceFragment caller, Preference pref) {
        final Fragment f =
                Fragment.instantiate(getActivity(), pref.getFragment(), pref.getExtras());
        f.setTargetFragment(caller, 0);
        if (f instanceof PreferenceFragment || f instanceof PreferenceDialogFragment) {
          //  startPreferenceFragment(f);
        } else {
           // startImmersiveFragment(f);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceStartScreen(PreferenceFragment caller, PreferenceScreen pref) {
        final Fragment f = new PrefsFragment();
        final Bundle args = new Bundle(1);
        args.putString(PreferenceFragment.ARG_PREFERENCE_ROOT, pref.getKey());
        f.setArguments(args);
        startPreferenceFragment(f);
        return true;
    }
}      
@SuppressLint("ValidFragment")
public  class PrefsFragment extends LeanbackPreferenceFragment {

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        // Load the preferences from an XML resource
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences, rootKey);
    }
}
```

Comment: share your code first

Comment: can you check i added

Comment: Error is at line 18 at xml file. Read error logcat carefully. Check your xml file

Comment: there is no line no 18 in my xml actually that error coming from leanback library class

Comment: I resolved the issue.  We have to set theme as          <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Leanback</item>
for the host activity

Answer (score 0):

I **solve** this issue by changing theme preference **Theme.Leanback**

On your manifest file :

```
<activity android:name=".ui.setting.YourSettingPrefActivity"
        android:exported="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Pref.LeanbackPreferences"/>
```

And here on styles.xml

```
<style name="Theme.Pref.LeanbackPreferences" parent="Theme.Leanback">
    <item name="preferenceTheme">@style/PreferenceThemeOverlay.v14.Leanback</item>
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/fastlane_background</item>
</style>
```